# How to compute total risk of a person?

Tags: risk, relative-risk

For a given disease there are some risk factors. I have compute total risk of a person, given presence or absence of individual risk factors. Also risk ratios for different risk factors are available from literature. Following table shows different risk factors, their associated risk ratios and whether they are present or absent (0 or 1) in a this given person:

```
Risk_factor  Risk_ratio  Risk_factor_present
AA              2.3         1
BB              1.5         0
CC              3.1         1
DD              2.7         0
EE              1.6         1
```

What would be the risk of this person as compared to one without any risk factors? How can I compute this value and its confidence interval? Will simple average be sufficient (taking value of 1 if risk factor is absent)? Do I need any further information? Thanks for your insight.

Comment: I am unsure of - total_risk = taking into account all the deceases OR total_risk = risk_of_THIS_decease? If 1st one is true -> Is there importance_factor involved? For e.g. acute decease is less potent than, say, chronic one.

Comment: For the sake of simplicity, lets assume there is no importance factor involved and all risk factors are independent. I could not understand your first statement.

Comment: I meant - For decease D1 - Risk Factors are AA, BB, CC, DD, EE. For decease D2 - Risk Factors might be DD, EE, FF, GG, For decease D3 - Risk Factors

Comment: I am considering here only one disease, for which AA, BB, CC, DD and EE are risk factors.